# change primary key data type

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, foreign-keys, primary-key, ddl

I am using PostgreSQL. e_id is the primary key and I want to change the data type from char(5) to integer.

```
  Column   |         Type          | Modifiers 
-----------+-----------------------+-----------
 e_id      | character(5)          | not null

     Column      |     Type     | Modifiers 
-----------------+--------------+-----------
 employee_e_id   | character(5) | not null
 product_prod_nr | character(5) | not null
 hours           | numeric      | not null
Indexes:
    "works_on_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (employee_e_id, product_prod_nr, hours)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "works_on_employee_e_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (employee_e_id) REFERENCES employee(e_id)
```

One table in my database already depends on that primary key.
Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do these things.I hope all of your present records in both tables are compatible with Integer type.

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE works_on DROP CONSTRAINT works_on_employee_e_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE works_on ALTER COLUMN employee_e_id TYPE INTEGER USING employee_e_id::INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN e_id TYPE INTEGER USING e_id::INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE works_on ADD CONSTRAINT works_on_employee_e_id_fkey 
                     FOREIGN KEY (employee_e_id) REFERENCES employee(e_id);
END;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5c3a289b499f70acbf9b42c790997cc8)